¿Cómo quitar los marcadores de posición de CKEditor 5?
Tengo el archivo ckeditor.js en una carpeta y en un script estoy aplicando el editor a un div.
El problema es que aparece por defecto un h1 con el contenido "Introduce tu título" y luego un <p>. Quiero que el lienzo aparezca vacío y no sé cómo lograrlo:


config = {
   placeholder: '',
};
CKSource.Editor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor'), config)
.catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
} );



